# Set text in AccessibilityNodeInfo

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm developing an Android Accessibility Service. I got an [AccessibilityNodeInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html) that represents an EditText. Is possibile to edit the contained text?

I tried with `mynode.setText("aaa")` but i get `IllegalStateException` as described in official documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: No, it is not possible to set the contents of an EditText from an AccessibilityService using AccessibilityNodeInfo. Accessibility nodes are only meant for reading information and performing a small set of actions (see AccessibilityNodeInfo.performAction). However, you could accomplish through an IME.

Comment: @alanv, how would you do that?

Comment: Actually, it looks I was wrong. As of API 18 you can use ACTION_PASTE to insert text from ClipboardManager. Combined with the text selection actions, you could effectively edit a portion of text; however, the API wasn't really intended for that and it may not work well.

Answer (score 27):

You can use  [ACTION_SET_TEXT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html#ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE) for >= android 21.
Here is the example of it:

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
if (source != null & event.getClassName().equals("android.widget.EditText")) {
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo
            .ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, "android");
    source.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Saved my day

Comment: What is the 'event' variable?